# Can I view the database of a MAUI project in Android Studio?

Tags: android, .net, visual-studio, maui, database-inspector

I have a .NET MAUI project that I am running on my Android device/ Simulator in debug mode. I need to view and update its database using Android Studio, since the Visual Studio IDE doesn't have a plugin for that. But in Android Studio, the .NET MAUI apps built with Visual Studio never show up. How can I use database inspector of Android Studio with my .NET MAUI app?

Comment: As far as I know, you can't do it

Answer (score 1):

If you mean an SQLite database that you create for your app *(e.g. using [sqlite-net-pcl](https://www.nuget.org/packages/sqlite-net-pcl))*, then you can't as stated in the [official Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/inspect/database). That's because .NET implementations are not the same as the native SQLite library that comes with Android.